# Terminology about computation and Finite algebra

Tags: terminology, algebra, universal-computation

I am looking for the name of something that may have one.

A *finite algebra* $\mathcal{A} = (E, \{f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_k\})$ is a non-empty set $E$ together with some functions $f_i$ from $E^{r_i} \to E$ where $r_i$ is a fixed integer (arity).

An *$n$-term* is a *term* on $n$ variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ over a finite algebra $\mathcal A$. A term is defined as usual by induction:

- Any element of $E$ and the variables $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ are terms
- If $t_1, \ldots, t_{r_i}$ are terms, then $f_i(t_1,\ldots, t_{r_i})$ is also a term.

An $n$-term $t$ *computes* a function $[t]\colon E^n \to E$ in an obvious way.

***Terminology question:*** How do we call finite algebras such that for every function $f\colon E^n\to E$, there exists a term $t$ such that $[t] = f$?

Famous example:
 $$(\{0, 1\}, \{\land, \lor, \lnot\})$$

Famous co-example:
 $$(\{0, 1\}, \{\land, \lor\})$$

Comment: why is the first an example ? what about projection to the first (resp. second) component ? Also you probably want to add "for every n smaller than some bound" in your definition.

Comment: The first one is an example thanks to the (logic) completeness of $\land, \lor,\lnot$. I don't get why you want to have "n smaller than some bound" ?

Comment: Functionally complete.

Comment: Sounds to be the used name indeed. Thanks a lot. Can you answer the question so I can close it?

Comment: ah sorry my bad misunderstood the definition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such algebras are called *functionally complete*. Also, what you call *terms* are actually called *polynomials*. In standard terminology, term operations have a more restricted definition that allows variables and the basic operations $f_i$, but not constants from $E$. Algebras that satisfy the stronger condition that every operation is represented by this kind of a term are called *primal*. See e.g. Burris&Sankappanavar, [*A Course in Universal Algebra*](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html).